# Angular(Ionic) Services and model dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I was told that for a Ionic project I must use a service for each object.

my models:

```
export class Document{
    idDocument: number;
    listFields: Fields[];
}
export class Field{
    idParentDocument: number;
    idLinkToOtherDocument: Document;
}
```

my services :

```
export class DocumentService{
    constructor(private http: httpService, private fieldService: FieldService){}

    getFields(document: Document){
       this.fieldService.getFieldsByDocumentId(document.id);
       //gets the fields of the document
    }

    getDocument(id: number){
       //gets the document and its fields
    }
}

export class FieldsService{
    constructor(private http: httpService, private documentService: DocumentService){}

    getParentDocument(field: Field){
       //gets the parent document of the field
    }

    getLinkedDocument(field: Field){
       //gets the linked document of the field
    }

    getFieldsByDocumentId(id: number){
       //gets the fields by document Id
    }
}
```

Sometimes I need to access objects from other objects like in my example, but as you can imagine this ends up in circular dependencies. I don't know what I am supposed to do, in java as an example you would simply have to call the functions but in angular you can't. I can go back to my previous design pattern where all functions was in objects and not in service, and I had to pass all other services (database service, server service...) but it would be a huge refactoring for something I was told was bad design (and I find it better with objectServices, I have access to all services without passing them as arguments)

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally neither i would pass services as arguments or inject them into each other. Refactoring them would cost you less then refactoring them later or try to maintain this code or fixing a bug. Lets breakdown it a little bit :

```
 getFields(document: Document){ // you only need a documentId not entire document object
       this.fieldService.getFieldsByDocumentId(document.id); 

    } 
//as the name say it return fields uses fields service you shouldn't have to redeclare it in document service.
// If someone wants to get fields of document he/she should use fields service ! 



export class FieldsService{
    constructor(private http: httpService, private documentService: DocumentService){}

    getParentDocument(field: Field){
      // returns document and it should belong to DocumentsService.
     // probably you will make an api call here do you need entire field object? NO
    }

    getLinkedDocument(field: Field){
       // same as above
    }

    getFieldsByDocumentId(id: number){
       // its ok.
    }
}
```

If your objects live through your application. Lets say when you don't need an API call to get a document's fields then i would suggest you to use something like [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) which helps you to keep your application's state centralized.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I tried to make a simple example to expose my problem, but actually sometimes document needs to get its fields for other reasons, as an example when I insert my document in database, I need to store its fields, I would like to make only one function insertDocument() that inserts everything, should I make a "relationService" like "FieldsDocumentService" ?

Comment: If your function needs a couple of more properties from field object. Define another type or interface or class or inline it that contains required or optional fields. For method you mentioned i would have at least method for that. One just inserts a document `insertDocument(Document)` and one with fields `insertDocumentWithFields(DocumentWithFields)` and so on and since the document is the main domain object here they should be handled by document service.

Comment: but I would need to call an insertField() in insertDocumentWithFields() in documentService, or I would have to reuse same code in documentService

Comment: I think you shouldn't inserting document and fields separately will cost you another request and you will have to wait first request to complete. Instead make a backend method that handles it at once.

Comment: That was an example. In my real project, I am in a document, this document has fields, so I want to get my document and its fields at once, and I don't want to repeat the code that gets fields. But then I am displaying my fields, now for each field I have to get the parent document attached to it (I try to make it simple it's hard to explain)